# Spotfire date difference using over function

Tags: analytics, spotfire

I have the following data set:

```
Item  ||  Date       || Client ID || Date difference
A     ||  12/12/2014 || 102       || 
A     ||  13/12/2014 || 102       || 1
B     ||  12/12/2014 || 141       || 
B     ||  17/12/2014 || 141       || 5
```

I would like to calculate the difference in years between the two dates when the client ID is the same. What expression can I use in a calculated column to get that value?

UPDATE

Hi

This would be the intended values calculated. My table has approximately 300,000 records in no particular order. Would I have to sort the physical table before using this formula? I used this example from another I found, my actual file has no item column. It is only the client ID, and date of the transaction. Thanks again for the help!

```
ClientId    Date        Days
 102         2014.12.12  0
 102         2014.12.13  1
 141         2014.12.12  0
 141         2014.12.17  5
 123         2014.12.01  0
 123         2014.12.02  1
 123         2014.12.04  2
```

Comment: it looks like you mean the difference in days, not years?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT 2015.07.15

got it, so if you want the difference from the last customer-date pair. this expression will give you the table you've listed above. spacing for readability:

```
DateDiff('day',
  First([Date) OVER (Intersect([ClientId], Previous([Date]))),
  [Date]
)
```

[image: Table viz of sample data plus this Calculated Column]

---

EDIT 2015.07.13

if you want to reduce this so that you can accurately aggregate `[Days]`, you can surround the above expression with an `If()`. I'll add some spacing to make this more readable:

```
If(
    [Date] = Min([Date]) OVER Intersect([ClientId], [Item]), 
    DateDiff( 'day', 
        Min([Date]) OVER Intersect([ClientId], [Item]), 
        Max([Date]) OVER Intersect([ClientId], [Item])
    )
    , 0
)
```

in English: "If the value of the [Date] column in this row matches the earliest date for this [ItemId] and [ClientId] combination, then put the number of days difference between the first and last [Date] for this [ItemId] and [ClientId] combination; otherwise, put zero."

it results in something like:

```
Item    ClientId    Date        Days
A       102         2014.12.12  1
A       102         2014.12.13  0
B       141         2014.12.12  5
B       141         2014.12.17  0
C       123         2014.12.01  2
C       123         2014.12.02  0
C       123         2014.12.03  0
```

**WARNING** that filters may break this calculation. for example, if you are filtering based on [Date] and, with the above table as an example, filter OUT all dates before 2014.12.13, Sum([Date]) will be 7 instead of 8 (because the first row has been filtered out).

---

you can use Spotfire's `OVER` functions to look at data points with common IDs across rows.

it looks like you've only got two rows per Client ID and Item ID, which helps us out! use the following formula:

```
DateDiff('day', Min([Date]) OVER Intersect([ClientId], [Item]), Max([Date]) OVER Intersect([ClientId], [Item]))
```

this will give you a column with the number of days difference between the two dates in each row:

```
Item    ClientId    Date        Days
A       102         2014.12.12  1
A       102         2014.12.13  1
B       141         2014.12.12  5
B       141         2014.12.17  5
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. This works perfectly for cases when there are only 2 items per client but some clients have more. For example, I am looking at cases when a client has 3 records, this formula will take calculate using the earliest and latest date. In these cases the earliest item should have a value of 0, middle record (middle date-earliest date), most recent record (most recent-middle record). Is there some way to get those values? Thanks again for the help!

Comment: if my edit doesn't solve your issue, can you describe your intended end result?

Comment: Thanks Niko! I tried that expression in a calculated column. What is the [Column2] value? I tried replacing it with the client ID and transaction date but in both cases the column came up with blank values. –

Comment: ah, sorry. that should be [Date]. I'll fix my answer now. I'm not sure why it doesn't work properly for you; I'll also add a screenshot.

Comment: @cookiemnstr247, if this answer helped you can you please accept it?

Answer (score 2):

I used the following solution to deal with groups that had more than 2 rows/dates.

First create a calculated column to provide a rank order by date within each group:

**RankDatePerUnit:**

```
  Rank([EventDate],[Group_Name])
```

Then another calculated column to do the date diff using an over expression to reference the previous date within the group.

**TimeSinceLastEvent:**

```
DateDiff("day",
   First([EventDate]) OVER (Intersect([Group_Name], Previous([RankDatePerUnit]))),
   [EventDate])
```

[image: Example Data]

Note: Duplicate date could be handled differently by using denserank. The above approach will not calculate a zero date diff between two rows from the same group with a duplicate time.  They'll both calculate their delta from an earlier date within the same group if one exists.