# LAG/LEAD using Spotfire custom expression

Tags: spotfire

My input data table looks like this

```
ID      AdmitDate
ABC001  1/1/2017
XYZ007  1/2/2017
XYZ002  1/3/2017
ABC001  1/4/2017
ABC001  1/7/2017
XYZ002  1/7/2017
```

And I am trying to retrieve previous admit date for each new visit. The output should be something like this.

```
ID      AdmitDate   PreviousAdmitDate
ABC001  1/1/2017    
XYZ007  1/2/2017    
XYZ002  1/3/2017    
ABC001  1/4/2017    1/1/2017
ABC001  1/7/2017    1/4/2017
XYZ002  1/7/2017    1/3/2017
```

In SQL I would have done something like...

```
LAG(AdmitDate, 1, Null) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY AdmitDate) AS PreviousAdmitDate
```

I tried the below solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31344663/spotfire-date-difference-using-over-function) post but didn't work.

```
First([AdmitDate]) OVER (Intersect([ID], Previous([AdmitDate])))
```

What would be the Spotfire custom expression way of doing it?

Answer (score 2):

@WeShall - Here are the steps:

**Step 1:** Add a calculated column which has decreasing counts of ID's.

```
Count([ID]) over (intersect([ID],AllNext([AdmitDate])))
```

**Step 2:** Now, using the calculated column from the previous step, add a calculated column which shows the previous date of the same ID.

```
Min([AdmitDate]) over (Intersect([ID],Next([decreasing_count])))
```

*Note: The column 'decreasing_count' can work in the background. It is not necessary to display it in the table.*

**Final Output table:**

[image]

Hope this helps.