# Spotfire date difference using over function if no previous in first rank

Tags: spotfire

I found a solution to half of my problem following this link : [Spotfire date difference using over function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31344663/spotfire-date-difference-using-over-function)

However, now I need to fill in the Rank 1 since it doesn't have a previous date?

Let's say I want the same result as in a post presented, however for the ones that do not have previous date to calculate (now empty with Rank 1), I want to add different calculation eg. column A- column B.
How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the SN() function in Spotfire? so SN(A,B) gives you A if not null, otherwise it gives you B